# pass a variable in the url in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am not able to a pass a variable value in the URL in Zend.

```
echo '<a href="/page/page-info/page_id/"' .$this->hidden_page_id. '"/">Back</a>';
```

if I simple echo $this->hidden_page_id I get the value on the above page. But When I pass it above through a link it does not show the value. Do I have to store it in a session or something?

Comment: "it does show the value" - That's good then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get when do a var_dump?

```
var_dump($this->hidden_page_id);
```

An advice, use View Helpers:

```
echo '<a href="' . $this->url(array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'page-info', 'page_id' => $this->hidden_page_id)) . '">Back</a>';
```