# Define what detail for which user -PHP-Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, html-table

I working with database through Zend Framework .I've selected some data and put them in table .
 *id* is primary key  and *phone* is another column in my table, if user press "detail" , he goes to another page , all I want is define what detail related to which user

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>detail</th>
      </tr>

        <?php 
            foreach ($this ->paginator as $key =>$value)
            {

                echo '<tr><td>'     .$value->id.'</td><td>'
                                    .$value->phone.'</td><td>'
                                    <td><a href = "details">
                                      go to detail for this user </a></td></tr>';

            }
        ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to get a details of specific user?

Comment: yes @IndrasinhBihola

Comment: You have to pass an ID in your details URL and fetch the details from your db in your next page.

Comment: Try this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387473/pass-a-variable-in-the-url-in-zend

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola thanks for link and your guidance, now I have this for example : http://localhost/books/detail8 and 8 is id , how to fetch the detail ?

Comment: Now to access it go to your `books controller` => `detail action` and add this code `$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('the key you given in your url for your id');`